# Hibernate SQLSyntaxErrorException - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Good morning, I'm dwelling with this error on a DAOImpl method from this morning... it happened all of a sudden..

This is my method:

```
public int postiOccupatiParcheggio(Park park) {
        Query pianiQuery = getSession().createQuery("from Piano p where p.park = :park");
        pianiQuery.setParameter("park", park);
        List <Piano> piani = pianiQuery.list();

        Query postiQuery = getSession().createQuery("from Posto p where p.piano in :piani");
        postiQuery.setParameterList("piani", piani);
        List<Posto> posti = postiQuery.list();

        Query query = getSession().createQuery("SELECT count(*) from Occupazione o where o.posto in :posti "
                + "and o.occupied = true and o.dateTime = (select max(oo.dateTime) from "
                + "Occupazione oo where o.posto = oo.posto)");
        query.setParameterList("posti", posti);
        Long r = null;
        int result = 0;
        try {
        r = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
        result = r.intValue();

        } catch(NoResultException nre) {
            result = 0;

        } 
        return result;
    }
```

I'm getting  this exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
 in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
 version for the right syntax to use near ')) and occupazion0_.isOccupied=1 and
 occupazion0_.date_time=(select max(occupazi' at line 1
```

and hibernate logs tells:

```
SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
```

I read that this is an error that occurs if you use some restricted variables names, but it's not the case, and most of all, everything went good till yesterday...

I'm using MySql 5.7.9 and with this property:
`hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

Comment: What is the value of `posti`?

Comment: just a hunch but i seem to remember the `in` argument must be in parentheses, i.e. `where o.posto in (:posti)`.

Comment: @Jens i had one List<Posto> posti empty... is this the error right?

Comment: Yes the value in the in clause can not be empty

Comment: Thank you! I will have to check for this in all the queries